# E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution)

Tags: debian, software-installation

I am using debian 9.I tried to install the tex application, but it didn't work.
Now I can't install any other application in my Debian machine.

```
root@debian:/etc/apt# apt-get install tuxpaint
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 perl : Depends: perl-base (= 5.24.1-3+deb9u4) but 5.24.1-3+deb9u2 is to be installed
        Depends: perl-modules-5.24 (>= 5.24.1-3+deb9u4) but 5.24.1-3+deb9u2 is to be installed
        Depends: libperl5.24 (= 5.24.1-3+deb9u4) but 5.24.1-3+deb9u2 is to be installed
 tuxpaint : Depends: tuxpaint-plugins-default (>= 1:0.9.22-1) but it is not going to be installed or
                     tuxpaint-plugins
            Depends: tuxpaint-data (= 1:0.9.22-3) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libsdl-mixer1.2 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libsdl-pango1 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: tuxpaint-config but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Additionally, when I try `apt --fix-broken install`:

```
root@debian:/home/midhun# apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  aptitude-common authbind bnd fonts-texgyre glassfish-jmac-api groovy ivy
  java-wrappers libaopalliance-java libasm-java libatinject-jsr330-api-java
  libbcpg-java libbcprov-java libbindex-java libbsh-java libcdi-api-java
  libcglib-java libclassworlds-java libcommons-cli-java libcommons-codec-java
  libcommons-collections3-java libcommons-httpclient-java libcommons-io-java
  libcommons-lang-java libcommons-lang3-java libcwidget3v5 libdom4j-java
  libdoxia-core-java libeasymock-java libeclipse-aether-java
  libfelix-osgi-obr-java libfindbugs-java
  libgeronimo-interceptor-3.0-spec-java libgoogle-gson-java
  libgpars-groovy-java libgradle-core-java libgradle-plugins-java
  libguava-java libguice-java libhawtjni-runtime-java libhttpclient-java
  libhttpcore-java libisorelax-java libjansi-java libjansi-native-java
  libjarjar-java libjatl-java libjaxen-java libjcifs-java
  libjcip-annotations-java libjcommander-java libjcsp-java libjdom1-java
  libjetty9-extra-java libjetty9-java libjformatstring-java libjline2-java
  libjna-java libjna-jni libjsoup-java libjsr166y-java libjsr305-java
  libkryo-java libkxml2-java liblogback-java libmaven-parent-java
  libmaven2-core-java libmaven3-core-java libminlog-java libmsv-java
  libmultiverse-core-java libnative-platform-java libnative-platform-jni
  libnekohtml-java libnetty-3.9-java libobjenesis-java libosgi-annotation-java
  libosgi-compendium-java libosgi-core-java libplexus-ant-factory-java
  libplexus-archiver-java libplexus-bsh-factory-java libplexus-cipher-java
  libplexus-classworlds-java libplexus-classworlds2-java libplexus-cli-java
  libplexus-component-annotations-java libplexus-component-metadata-java
  libplexus-container-default-java libplexus-container-default1.5-java
  libplexus-containers-java libplexus-containers1.5-java
  libplexus-interactivity-api-java libplexus-interpolation-java
  libplexus-io-java libplexus-sec-dispatcher-java libplexus-utils-java
  libplexus-utils2-java libpolyglot-maven-java libqdox-java libqdox2-java
  libreflectasm-java librelaxng-datatype-java librhino-java
  libsimple-http-java libsisu-inject-java libsisu-plexus-java
  libspring-beans-java libspring-core-java libtaglibs-standard-impl-java
  libtaglibs-standard-spec-java libtcnative-1 libwagon-java libwagon2-java
  libxbean-java libxom-java libxpp2-java libxpp3-java libxstream-java
  libyaml-snake-java libyaml-tiny-perl ps2eps testng texlive-font-utils
  texlive-fonts-recommended-doc texlive-generic-recommended texlive-latex-base
  texlive-latex-recommended texlive-pictures tipa
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libperl5.24 perl-base perl-modules-5.24
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libperl5.24 perl-base perl-modules-5.24
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 260 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/7,313 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 258549 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../perl-base_5.24.1-3+deb9u4_i386.deb ...
Unpacking perl-base (5.24.1-3+deb9u4) over (5.24.1-3+deb9u2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/perl-base_5.24.1-3+deb9u4_i386.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/perl-base/lib.pm' to '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/perl-base/lib.pm.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/perl-base_5.24.1-3+deb9u4_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@debian:/home/midhun# ^C
```

The output of grep ^ /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*} is

```
root@debian:/usr/bin# grep ^ /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*}
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb apps
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb apps
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/java-8-debian.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/java-8-debian.list:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/java-8-debian.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/java-8-debian.list.save:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list:deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_9.x stretch main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list:deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_9.x stretch main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list.save:deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_9.x stretch main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list.save:deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_9.x stretch main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list:deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main contrib
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list.save:deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main contrib
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list:deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list.save:deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-atom-cosmic.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu cosmic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-atom-cosmic.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu cosmic main
root@debian:/usr/bin#
```

This is the output of command df -h

```
root@debian:/home/midhun# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            4.0G     0  4.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           807M  9.4M  798M   2% /run
/dev/sda11       91G   11G   76G  12% /
/dev/sda13      9.2G  9.1G     0 100% /usr
tmpfs           4.0G   29M  4.0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           4.0G     0  4.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda15      9.2G   37M  8.6G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda16      9.2G  869M  7.8G  10% /usr/local
/dev/sda12       19G   18G   32M 100% /home
/dev/sda14      9.2G  4.6G  4.1G  53% /var
/dev/sda18      7.3G   34M  6.9G   1% /srv
/dev/sda19       15G   73M   14G   1% /boot
/dev/sda17      9.2G  1.2G  7.5G  14% /opt
tmpfs           807M   16K  807M   1% /run/user/115
tmpfs           807M   28K  807M   1% /run/user/1000
```

How to make some space in /usr?

Comment: http://paste.debian.net/1047681/


http://paste.debian.net/1047682/

Comment: "_cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/perl-base/lib.pm' to '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/perl-base/lib.pm.dpkg-new': failed to write (**No space left on device**)_"

Comment: Hello and welcome to the U&l stack exchange! Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) for information on how to best post to this site. To get to your question, it appears according to your output that your disk or partition `/usr` is out of space. Consider making some space on the disk where `/usr/lib` is located. [Please update your post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/476059/edit) with output of your `sources.list` or `sources.list.d` depending on which one you use. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome , please add the output of `grep ^ /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*}`

Answer (score 2):

Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` as described on the [official documentataion](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list). Or copy and past the following line into the termial:

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
EOF
```

Remove the Ubuntu repository trusty , xenial and cosmic :

```
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-atom-cosmic.list
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/java-8-debian.list
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list
```

Then run:

```
apt update && apt dist-upgrade
apt --fix-broken install
```

**Edit**

You can clean up your system using:

```
apt autoremove
apt clean 
apt autoclean
```

Removing the old kernels and kernel headers, you can list them through:

```
dpkg --list 'linux-headers*'
dpkg --list 'linux-image*'
```

Then install and configure the `localpurge` pacakge (see `man localepurge`) then run it :

```
localepurge
```

a sample output:

```
localepurge: Disk space freed in /usr/* : X KiB
```

Comment: This answer definitely moves in the right direction on my broken box. I ran into issues with the update command due to unresolved public keys. This can be fixed by following the procedure at: https://chrisjean.com/fix-apt-get-update-the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key-is-not-available/

Comment: @mds' link solved my issue

Answer (score 2):

use

> sudo apt autoremove

and then install blechbit by

> sudo apt install bleachbit

bleachbit will help you clean unnecessary files off your device