# Linux Debian Bullseye - not able to install packages after uninstalling libreoffice

Tags: debian, apt, libreoffice

I uninstalled libreoffice and its packages to replace it with another office software. After this step I cannot use `apt` properly. Doing `sudo apt-get install xxxx` throws this error message (it always says 54 megs will be freed, though storage should be used, rather than removed):

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
discord is already the newest version (0.0.17).
The following packages will be REMOVED:
libreoffice-common
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 54.0 MB disk space will be freed.
```

I also cannot install libreoffice because it has broken packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libreoffice : Depends: libreoffice-writer but it is not installable
           Depends: libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer but it is not installable or
                    libreoffice-avmedia-backend-vlc but it is not installable
           Recommends: libreoffice-librelogo but it is not installable
           Recommends: libreoffice-nlpsolver but it is not installable
           Recommends: libreoffice-report-builder but it is not installable
           Recommends: libreoffice-script-provider-bsh but it is not installable
           Recommends: libreoffice-script-provider-js but it is not installable
           Recommends: libreoffice-script-provider-python but it is not installable
           Recommends: libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql but it is not installable
           Recommends: libreoffice-wiki-publisher but it is not installable
           Recommends: libreoffice-java-common (>= 1:6.1.5~) but it is not installable
 libreoffice-base : Depends: uno-libs3 (>= 5.1.0~alpha) but it is not installable
                Recommends: libreoffice-writer but it is not installable
                Recommends: libreoffice-java-common (>= 1:6.1.5~) but it is not installable
 libreoffice-base-core : Depends: uno-libs3 (>= 5.3.0~alpha) but it is not installable
 libreoffice-base-drivers : Depends: uno-libs3 (>= 5.3.0~alpha) but it is not installable
                        Recommends: libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb but it is not installable
                        Recommends: libreoffice-sdbc-firebird but it is not installable
 libreoffice-calc : Depends: uno-libs3 (>= 5.3.0~alpha) but it is not installable
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:6.1.5) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: uno-libs3 (>= 6.1.5-3+deb10u7) but it is not installable
 libreoffice-draw : Depends: uno-libs3 (>= 5.3.0~alpha) but it is not installable
 libreoffice-impress : Depends: uno-libs3 (>= 5.3.0~alpha) but it is not installable
                   Recommends: libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer but it is not installable or
                               libreoffice-avmedia-backend-vlc but it is not installable
 libreoffice-math : Depends: uno-libs3 (>= 5.1.0~alpha) but it is not installable
 libreoffice-report-builder-bin : Depends: uno-libs3 (>= 5.1.0~alpha) but it is not installable
  python3-uno : Depends: python3 (< 3.8) but 3.9.2-3 is to be installed
           Depends: python3.7 but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: uno-libs3 (>= 5.3.0~alpha) but it is not installable
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Hae you done `apt update` yet?

Comment: @roaima The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 83FBA1751378B444
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu kinetic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 83FBA1751378B444
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu kinetic InRelease' is not signed.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: You've broken your Debian system by using Ubuntu repositories. This answer may help https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/476078/100397 replacing "stretch" with "buster" in your case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/476059/e-unmet-dependencies-try-apt-fix-broken-install-with-no-packages-or-speci)

Comment: I tried to follow the answer given on that link, but all of those commands failed on the same thing i described above. It says "54 MB will be removed" and than it fails.

Comment: @LukaKralik please show us (in your question) what you've tried. Why do you think that removing 54 MB of LibreOffice to complete the removal is a problem? Is there something else it's telling you that you've omitted from your question? Have you run `apt-get update`? That was my first response, and it remains unanswered in your question.

Comment: My response is the error, thrown at me after running apt-get update